# I'm having issues with Phaser 3 collisions

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I created 2 objects (one solid circle and a stroke circle). But they simply don't collide as expected.

Here is my code:

```
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    backgroundColor: "#f5bd22",
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 90 },
            debug: false
        }
    }
}

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

let circle;
let hollowCircle;

function preload() {

}

function create() {
    circle = this.add.circle(200, 200, 50, '#f5bd22');

    hollowCircle = this.add.graphics();
    hollowCircle.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
    hollowCircle.strokeCircle(200, 200, 100);

    this.physics.world.enable([circle, hollowCircle]);

    hollowCircle.body.gravity.y = -90;
    this.physics.add.collider(circle, hollowCircle);
}

function update() {

}
```

It's creating a stroke circle with a solid circle inside. The gravity is set 90 to the solid and 0 to the stroke.
When the code runs, the solid circle falls and the stroke keep static. But the two circles touch and nothing happens.

Comment: If my answer solved your question please consider accepting it with the green checkmark under the upvoting. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this what you want to do, can't be done like this. Arcade physics just collide on the outside of physics bodies. Also if you look at the debug bounding boxes you can see the physics-box for the "hollowCircle" is in the top left *(**beware:** `physics` and `graphics` Gameobject, don't react as other GameObjects in phaser)*.

[image: Screenshot Bounding box]

That said, if you want this effect, an easy solution would be to create several small Physics object the cover the outline of the "hollow" - Shape, and than setting the collision with these objects.

**Here a Small Demo:**
*(Here I'm creating a  circle with 32 small rectangles so keep the shape, and I made the physics-box of the inner Circle round so that it looks a bit better)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    backgroundColor: "#f5bd22",
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:  { y: 90 },
            // turn on to show the created Objects
            // debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create
    },
}; 

function createCircle(scene, x, y, radius){

  // CREATE VISUALS
  let displayCircle = scene.add.circle(x, y, radius).setStrokeStyle(2,0x000000);
  
  // CREATE PHYSICS PART
  const circle = new Phaser.Geom.Circle(x, y, radius);
  const points = circle.getPoints(32);
  let boxes = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
      const p = points[i];

      let box = scene.add.rectangle(p.x - 2, p.y - 2, 4, 4);
      // with the second parameter I'm making the object(s) static, so no need for the -90 gravity
      let boxPhysics = scene.physics.add.existing(box, true);
      boxes.push(box);
  }
    
  return boxes;
}


function create() {
    let circle = this.add.circle(200, 80, 30, '#f5bd22');
    let circlePhysics = this.physics.add.existing(circle);
    circlePhysics.body.setCircle(30);

    let helperBoxes = createCircle(this, 200, 100, 70)
    
    this.physics.add.collider(circle, helperBoxes);
}

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> To see what is going on turn on the debug flag in the `config` on again.

> ***btw:** as an alternative you could use matterjs [here are some examples](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/physics/matterjs). With the matter engine more complex physics-object combinations are possible.*